# Flash messages with flask-bootstrap and flask-nav

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask, flash-message

I'm using `flask-bootstrap` to use the Bootstrap front-end for a flask web application. Unfortunately, since I've started using `flask-bootstrap` and `flask-nav`, I'm not able to display flash messages.

This is the `base.html`:

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %} 
{% block navbar %}
  {{ nav.mynavbar.render() }}
{% endblock %}

<html>
 <body>
    <hr>
    <div class='container'>
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
          <ul class=flashes>
          {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{ message }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      {% endwith %}
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is one of the view that should flash a message when a change is saved:

```
@app.route('/model/<model_name>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(model_name):
    """Edit model's configuration.

    Args:
        model_name [str]: The name of the model we want to change the
        configuration.
    """
    # return to index page if model is not found in the database
    model = DSModel.query.filter_by(name=model_name).first()
    if not model:
        flash('Model {} not found.'.format(model_name))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    # pre-load current model's configuration
    form = ConfigurationForm()

    # if it's a POST request, it means the user is trying to change the model's
    # configuration. Save changes in the database
    if request.method == 'POST':  # and form.validate_on_submit():
        model.configuration.configuration = form.value.data
        model.configuration.datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.add(model)
        db.session.commit()

        flash('Your changes have been saved.', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('edit', model_name=model_name))
    else:
        form.value.data = model.configuration.configuration
    return render_template('edit.html', form=form)
```

Finally, this is the `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_nav import Nav
from flask_nav.elements import Navbar, View
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

nav = Nav()

@nav.navigation()
def mynavbar():
    return Navbar(
        'Dashboard',
        View('Home', 'index'),
        View('Login', 'login')
    )


app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)
nav.init_app(app)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


from app import views, models
```

I think there must be something funky with my `base.html` file, but I'm not terribly familiar with HTML, so I'm not able to find what's wrong. I've looked into examples online (i.e. [here](https://github.com/allisson/flask-example/blob/master/templates/base.html#L90)), but the format seems to be pretty similar to what I'm doing.

EDIT: This is the `edit.html` file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Update configuration</h1>
<form action='' method='post' name='configuration'>
    <p>
    Please update the current model configuration:<br>
    {{ form.value(cols='150', rows='20') }}
    <p><input type='submit' value='Save'></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `<div class=container>...</div>` with all stuff should be inside the `content` block.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're suggesting. I was hoping to write everything withing the `with` block just once, within the `base.html` template. So that I could re-use it in other templates, simply extending `base.html`.

Comment: I don't mean add something extra. Just  move all things between body to `{%block content%}things goes here{%endblock%}`

Comment: I see! Sorry for the confusion. Even after doing it, unfortunately the messages don't show up.

Comment: Could you show your other template (`edit.html`)?

Comment: Sure, let me add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your base.html to this:

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %} 
{% block navbar %}
  {{ nav.mynavbar.render() }}
{% endblock %}

<html>
 <body>
    <hr>
    <div class='container'>
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
          <ul class=flashes>
          {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{ message }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}
     </div>
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```